# roslaunch could not find package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

recently I installed ros2 foxy on my ubuntu 20 system where I already have ros1 noetic. usually within the workspace whenever we type roslaunch on terminal we get the packages inside the workspace right. but now whenever I type roslaunch in my workspace I get the following.

```
akash-j@linuxadmin-ThinkPad-L490:~/ur5_ws$ roslaunch 
build/             .catkin_workspace  devel/             src/
akash-j@linuxadmin-ThinkPad-L490:~/ur5_ws$ roslaunch
```

instead of getting the packages, I am getting the above, and every time I need to give the full path to launch the file.

in addition to it when I try to sudo apt update I get the following message.

```
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list:1
```

i dont know whats wrong here

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386986/roslaunch-could-not-find-package/) by [akash12124234](https://answers.ros.org/users/76117/akash12124234/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2021-09-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello @akash12124234,

1. Can you please check which ros version is currently active you can do so by executing this command in the terminal.
   `echo $ROS_DISTRO` or `rosversion -d`
2. You need to check which ros environment is selected: If you are using ROS Noetic then you can source notice by executing `source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash` or For foxy you need to source `source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash` these things should be done every time once you open a new terminal.
3. Then you have to check about your project workspace and inside packages, whether it is of a specific version. You also need to source workspace and then I think you will be able to run.

Note: You should also check your .bashrc file if your terminal is sourcing by default environment. If it is doing, you can follow steps 1 and 2 for a specific version source.

I think you can get some help from this answer; please feel free to comment if you have any issues.

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [akash12124234](https://answers.ros.org/users/76117/akash12124234/) on 2021-09-21**:
I tried all the steps mentioned above before . nothing helped . usually, when we type roslaunch and enter tab we get all the possibilities right. I am getting something different.

akash-j@linuxadmin-ThinkPad-L490:~/simple$ roslaunch
build/             .catkin_workspace  devel/             src/

if you want to see any of my files I can show you

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-09-21**:
Once, try to write and check your launch file is executing. If yes, then it may be the problem of [auto-complete](https://wiki.hanzheteng.com/linux/ros/roslaunch).

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-09-22**:
You can create a new answer and tick your answer. Provide an appropriate description.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I uninstalled ros1,2. and reinstalled them now its working fine

---

Originally posted by [akash12124234](https://answers.ros.org/users/76117/akash12124234/) with karma: 32 on 2021-09-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1